# Calling activity method from fragment showing null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have some methods in MainActivity and trying to access from fragment. But the activity is showing null.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
PermissionResultListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

public boolean requestPermissionStorage() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.storage_permission_request_title))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.storage_permission_request_summary))
                .setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                Const.EXTDIR_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false);

        alert.create().show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


@TargetApi(23)
public void requestSystemWindowsPermission() {
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, Const.SYSTEM_WINDOWS_CODE);
    }
}

@TargetApi(23)
private void setSystemWindowsPermissionResult() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            mPermissionResultListener.onPermissionResult(Const.SYSTEM_WINDOWS_CODE,
                    new String[]{"System Windows Permission"},
                    new int[]{PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED});
        } else {
            mPermissionResultListener.onPermissionResult(Const.SYSTEM_WINDOWS_CODE,
                    new String[]{"System Windows Permission"},
                    new int[]{PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED});
        }
    } else {
        mPermissionResultListener.onPermissionResult(Const.SYSTEM_WINDOWS_CODE,
                new String[]{"System Windows Permission"},
                new int[]{PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED});
    }
}


public void requestPermissionAudio() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                Const.AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case Const.EXTDIR_REQUEST_CODE:
            if ((grantResults.length > 0) &&
                    (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                Log.d(Const.TAG, "write storage Permission Denied");
                fab.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                Log.d(Const.TAG, "write storage Permission granted");
                createDir();
            }
    }

    if (mPermissionResultListener != null) {
        mPermissionResultListener.onPermissionResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}


public void setPermissionResultListener(PermissionResultListener mPermissionResultListener) {
    this.mPermissionResultListener = mPermissionResultListener;
}
}
```

SettingActivity.java

```
public class SettingActivity extends AppCompatPrefernceActivity   {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsPreferenceFragment()).commit();


}
public static class SettingsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
        , PermissionResultListener, OnDirectorySelectedListerner {

    /**
     * SharedPreferences object to read the persisted settings
     */
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    /**
     * ListPreference to choose the recording resolution
     */
    private ListPreference res;

    /**
     * CheckBoxPreference to manage audio recording via mic setting
     */
    private CheckBoxPreference recaudio;

    /**
     * CheckBoxPreference to manage onscreen floating control setting
     */
    private CheckBoxPreference floatingControl;


    /**
     * FolderChooser object to choose the directory where the video has to be saved to.
     */
    private FolderChooser dirChooser;

    /**
     * MainActivity object
     */
    private MainActivity activity;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            activity = (MainActivity) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " Not MainActivity class instance");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Initialize various listeners and settings preferences.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState default savedInstance bundle sent by Android runtime
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        setPermissionListener();


        String defaultSaveLoc = (new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Const.APPDIR)).getPath();

        prefs = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
        res = (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.res_key));
        ListPreference fps = (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.fps_key));
        ListPreference bitrate = (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.bitrate_key));
        recaudio = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.audiorec_key));
        ListPreference filenameFormat = (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.filename_key));
        EditTextPreference filenamePrefix = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.fileprefix_key));
        dirChooser = (FolderChooser) findPreference(getString(R.string.savelocation_key));
        floatingControl = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_floating_control_key));
        CheckBoxPreference touchPointer = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("touch_pointer");
        //Set previously chosen directory as initial directory
        dirChooser.setCurrentDir(getValue(getString(R.string.savelocation_key), defaultSaveLoc));

        ListPreference theme = (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_theme_key));
        theme.setSummary(theme.getEntry());

        //Set the summary of preferences dynamically with user choice or default if no user choice is made
        updateScreenAspectRatio();
        updateResolution(res);
        fps.setSummary(getValue(getString(R.string.fps_key), "30"));
        float bps = bitsToMb(Integer.parseInt(getValue(getString(R.string.bitrate_key), "7130317")));
        bitrate.setSummary(bps + " Mbps");
        dirChooser.setSummary(getValue(getString(R.string.savelocation_key), defaultSaveLoc));
        filenameFormat.setSummary(getFileSaveFormat());
        filenamePrefix.setSummary(getValue(getString(R.string.fileprefix_key), "recording"));

        //If record audio checkbox is checked, check for record audio permission
        if (recaudio.isChecked())
            requestAudioPermission();

        //If floating controls is checked, check for system windows permission
        if (floatingControl.isChecked())
            requestSystemWindowsPermission();



        //set callback for directory change
        dirChooser.setOnDirectoryClickedListerner(this);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the summary of resolution settings preference
     *
     * @param pref object of the resolution ListPreference
     */
    private void updateResolution(ListPreference pref) {
        pref.setSummary(getValue(getString(R.string.res_key), getNativeRes()));
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the device's native resolution
     *
     * @return device resolution
     */
    private String getNativeRes() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getRealDisplayMetrics();
        return getScreenWidth(metrics) + "x" + getScreenHeight(metrics);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the available resolution based on aspect ratio
     */
    private void updateScreenAspectRatio() {
        Const.ASPECT_RATIO aspect_ratio = getAspectRatio();
        Log.d(Const.TAG, "Aspect ratio: " + aspect_ratio);
        CharSequence[] entriesValues = getResolutionEntriesValues(aspect_ratio);
        res.setEntries(entriesValues);
        res.setEntryValues(entriesValues);
    }

    /**
     * Get resolutions based on the device's aspect ratio
     *
     * @param aspectRatio {@link com.orpheusdroid.screenrecorder.Const.ASPECT_RATIO} of the device
     * @return entries for the resolution
     */
    private CharSequence[] getResolutionEntriesValues(Const.ASPECT_RATIO aspectRatio) {

        ArrayList<String> entries;
        switch (aspectRatio) {
            case AR16_9:
                entries = buildEntries(R.array.resolutionsArray_16_9);
                break;
            case AR18_9:
                entries = buildEntries(R.array.resolutionValues_18_9);
                break;
            default:
                entries = buildEntries(R.array.resolutionsArray_16_9);
                break;
        }

        String[] entriesArray = new String[entries.size()];
        return entries.toArray(entriesArray);
    }

    /**
     * Build resolutions from the arrays.
     *
     * @param resID resource ID for the resolution array
     * @return ArrayList of available resolutions
     */
    private ArrayList<String> buildEntries(int resID) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getRealDisplayMetrics();
        int width = getScreenWidth(metrics);
        int height = getScreenHeight(metrics);
        String nativeRes = width + "x" + height;
        ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(resID)));
        Iterator<String> entriesIterator = entries.iterator();
        while (entriesIterator.hasNext()) {
            String entry = entriesIterator.next();
            String[] widthHeight = entry.split("x");
            if (width < Integer.parseInt(widthHeight[0]) || height < Integer.parseInt(widthHeight[1])) {
                entriesIterator.remove();
            }
        }
        if (!entries.contains(nativeRes))
            entries.add(nativeRes);
        return entries;
    }


    /**
     * Returns object of DisplayMetrics
     *
     * @return DisplayMetrics
     */
    private DisplayMetrics getRealDisplayMetrics(){
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        window.getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
        return metrics;
    }


    /**
     * Get width of screen in pixels
     *
     * @return screen width
     */
    private int getScreenWidth(DisplayMetrics metrics) {
        return metrics.widthPixels;
    }

    /**
     * Get height of screen in pixels
     *
     * @return Screen height
     */
    private int getScreenHeight(DisplayMetrics metrics) {
        return metrics.heightPixels;
    }


    /**
     * Get aspect ratio of the screen
     */
    private Const.ASPECT_RATIO getAspectRatio() {
        float screen_width = getScreenWidth(getRealDisplayMetrics());
        float screen_height = getScreenHeight(getRealDisplayMetrics());
        float aspectRatio;
        if (screen_width > screen_height) {
            aspectRatio = screen_width / screen_height;
        } else {
            aspectRatio = screen_height / screen_width;
        }
        return Const.ASPECT_RATIO.valueOf(aspectRatio);
    }

    /**
     * Set permission listener in the {@link MainActivity} to handle permission results
     */
    private void setPermissionListener() {
        if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
            activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            activity.setPermissionResultListener(this);
        }
    }




    /**
     * Get the persisted value for the preference from default sharedPreference
     *
     * @param key String represnting the sharedpreference key to fetch
     * @param defVal String Default value if the preference does not exist
     * @return String the persisted preference value or default if not found
     */
    private String getValue(String key, String defVal) {
        return prefs.getString(key, defVal);
    }

    /**
     * Method to convert bits per second to MB/s
     *
     * @param bps float bitsPerSecond
     * @return float
     */
    private float bitsToMb(float bps) {
        return bps / (1024 * 1024);
    }

    //Register for OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener when the fragment resumes
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    //Unregister for OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener when the fragment pauses
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    //When user changes preferences, update the summary accordingly
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
        Preference pref = findPreference(s);
        if (pref == null) return;
        switch (pref.getTitleRes()) {
            case R.string.preference_resolution_title:
                updateResolution((ListPreference) pref);
                break;
            case R.string.preference_fps_title:
                String fps = String.valueOf(getValue(getString(R.string.fps_key), "30"));
                pref.setSummary(fps);
                break;
            case R.string.preference_bit_title:
                float bps = bitsToMb(Integer.parseInt(getValue(getString(R.string.bitrate_key), "7130317")));
                pref.setSummary(bps + " Mbps");
                break;
            case R.string.preference_filename_format_title:
                pref.setSummary(getFileSaveFormat());
                break;
            case R.string.preference_audio_record_title:
                requestAudioPermission();
                break;
            case R.string.preference_filename_prefix_title:
                EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference) pref;
                etp.setSummary(etp.getText());
                ListPreference filename = (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.filename_key));
                filename.setSummary(getFileSaveFormat());
                break;
            case R.string.preference_floating_control_title:
                requestSystemWindowsPermission();
                break;
            case R.string.preference_show_touch_title:
                CheckBoxPreference showTouchCB = (CheckBoxPreference)pref;
                if (showTouchCB.isChecked() && !hasPluginInstalled()){
                    showTouchCB.setChecked(false);
                    showDownloadAlert();
                }
                break;
            case R.string.preference_crash_reporting_title:
                CheckBoxPreference crashReporting = (CheckBoxPreference)pref;
                CheckBoxPreference anonymousStats = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_anonymous_statistics_key));
                if(!crashReporting.isChecked())
                    anonymousStats.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case R.string.preference_anonymous_statistics_title:
                break;
            case R.string.preference_theme_title:
                activity.recreate();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * show an alert to download the plugin when the plugin is not found
     */
    private void showDownloadAlert() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.alert_plugin_not_found_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.alert_plugin_not_found_message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        try {
                            getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.orpheusdroid.screencamplugin")));
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) { // if there is no Google Play on device
                            getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.orpheusdroid.screencamplugin")));
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                })
                .create().show();
    }

    /**
     * Check if "show touches" plugin is installed.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    private boolean hasPluginInstalled(){
        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo("com.orpheusdroid.screencamplugin",PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(Const.TAG, "Plugin not installed");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Method to concat file prefix with dateTime format
     */
    public String getFileSaveFormat() {
        String filename = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.filename_key), "yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");
        String prefix = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.fileprefix_key), "recording");
        return prefix + "_" + filename;
    }

    /**
     * Method to request android permission to record audio
     */
    public void requestAudioPermission() {
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.requestPermissionAudio();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to request android system windows permission to show floating controls
     * <p>
     *     Shown only on devices above api 23 (Marshmallow)
     * </p>
     */
    private void requestSystemWindowsPermission() {
        if (activity != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            activity.requestSystemWindowsPermission();
        } else {
            Log.d(Const.TAG, "API is < 23");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show snackbar with permission Intent when the user rejects write storage permission
     */
    private void showSnackbar() {
        Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab), R.string.snackbar_storage_permission_message,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(R.string.snackbar_storage_permission_action_enable,
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (activity != null){
                            activity.requestPermissionStorage();
                        }
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    /**
     * Show a dialog when the permission to storage is denied by the user during startup
     */
    private void showPermissionDeniedDialog(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setTitle(R.string.alert_permission_denied_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.alert_permission_denied_message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        if (activity != null){
                            activity.requestPermissionStorage();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        showSnackbar();
                    }
                })
                .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create().show();
    }

    //Permission result callback to process the result of Marshmallow style permission request
    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Const.EXTDIR_REQUEST_CODE:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)) {
                    Log.d(Const.TAG, "Storage permission denied. Requesting again");
                    dirChooser.setEnabled(false);
                    showPermissionDeniedDialog();
                } else if((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                    dirChooser.setEnabled(true);
                }
                return;
            case Const.AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    Log.d(Const.TAG, "Record audio permission granted.");
                    recaudio.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    Log.d(Const.TAG, "Record audio permission denied");
                    recaudio.setChecked(false);
                }
                return;
            case Const.SYSTEM_WINDOWS_CODE:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    Log.d(Const.TAG, "System Windows permission granted");
                    floatingControl.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    Log.d(Const.TAG, "System Windows permission denied");
                    floatingControl.setChecked(false);
                }
            default:
                Log.d(Const.TAG, "Unknown permission request with request code: " + requestCode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectorySelected() {
        Log.d(Const.TAG, "In settings fragment");
        if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onDirectoryChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to ask runtime permission from fragment using the methods mention in MainActivity. But activity  = getActivity() is showing null.

I have tried using onAttach method in fragment, it is also not working showing class cast exception.

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            activity = (MainActivity) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " Not MainActivity class instance");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as  settingActivity is the container of Fragment, you cant get the context from mainactivity unless mainactivity is container of fragment.

Solution -  you can make function static or write them in extends Application Class or settingactivity